# Multiple select option in list form filed type not working Joomla 3.2

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I am facing strange problem with Joomla form field I have added a field set type as list and set attribute to `multiple="true"`. Here the code:

```
<field name="optional"
            type="list"
            label="Optional"
            description="Optional endorsements"
            class="inputbox"
            size="5"
            multiple="true"
         >

         <option value="Water">
                Water</option>
        <option value="Foundation">
            Foundation</option>
</field>
```

Now when I save the form then only one value get saved when select the multiple values. I don't know what's the problem, if someone have any solution for that please help me.

Answer (score 4):

You don't get value, because you're not getting and saving it right. This is what you need to do:
In your jTable `bind()` method you need to add following lines:

```
if (isset($array['optional']) && is_array($array['optional'])) {
  $registry = new JRegistry;
  $registry->loadArray($array['optional']);
  $array['optional'] = (string) $registry;
}
```

This will convert your multiple select array into string, which will be saved in database.

And then in your model's method `getItem` you need to add following lines:

```
if ($item = parent::getItem($pk)) {
  $registry = new JRegistry;
  $registry->loadString($item->optional);
  $item->optional = $registry->toArray();
}
```

This will convert databse string back to array and pass it to your jForm.

Comment: Here's only sample code, hope it helps. If it doesn't work, please share with me your jTable bind method, and jModel getItem method then i'll be able to help more.

Comment: Tried that, works for me in Joomla 3.6.x, Joomla stores now a JSON-Object in the database: {"0":"1","1":5} instead of 1,5. Works perfectly with my SQL-list field.

Comment: Great. Thanks Mate. You made my day. Cheers

Comment: @di3sel I did some amendment to Joomla 3x banner component in the backend. I added a multiple selected list of countries to the form. My problem is how to save the data to the database. I dont know where exactly I am to place the your above code. please kindly help me... thanks.

Comment: @DavidAddoteye In my provided example table's field name is called "optional" but you can use any field name here (in your case it would probably be countries);
Also in description files are provided: if you're using JTable to store data to your component's database, use that file and override default bind() method also your Model's getItem method.

Comment: I am having a very similar scenario, in my case I need to store multiple values in a custom user field, I am new to joomla and do not know where are the locations of the files I need to update with di3sel recommendation. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

First, @di3sel is totally correct. I am just adding something that could not fit in a comment.

It is also fine if you add the second code to `jTable:load` method instead of the `jModel::getItem`. But the code will then change a little. Please note we have to use `$this` in place of `$item` in that case.

```php
parent::load($pk);

$registry = new JRegistry;
$registry->loadString($this->optional);
$this->optional = $registry->toArray();
```

This is also good in the view that only one class-file needs to be modified. Hope this helps at least someone.